# Returning a collection of specific elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get all `li` elements starting from second item (`level_2`) onwards using jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li class="item level_1">text1</li>
    <li class="item level_2">text2</li>
    <li class="item level_3">text3</li>
    <li class="item level_4">text4</li>
    <li class="item level_3">text5</li>
    <li class="item level_2">text2</li>
    <li class="item level_3">text3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "started from second"?

Comment: what do u mean listed from second? you mean starting from text2 node ?

Comment: `$('ul li:not(:first)')`

Answer (score 2):

Look into using [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

```
$("li").eq(0).nextAll("li");
```

This will select all `<li>`s starting with the second one.

Comment: Or, more concisely, `$('li:gt(0)');` or `$('li').slice(1);` (maybe).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to filter a list of elements, in this case `.not` will work well for you.

```
$('li').not(':first-child');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-child:

```
$('li.item:nth-child(n+1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector and select all `li` with an index greater than zero :

```
$('li:gt(0)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `.slice`.

```
var $li = $('ul li');
var $li_from_second = $li.slice(1);
```